# on('close') events for TCP connections with http vs net - node.js

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, http, tcp

I've found that the on('data') event doesn't fire in a simple http server connected with a simple socket. Here are two servers, one with the `net` package, the other with `http`, and their associated outputs:

**net server**

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 8080;

net.createServer(function(socket) {        
     socket.on('error', function (e) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(({err:e, msg: "Request Stream Error", code: 500})))
     })

    socket.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('REQUEST CLOSING');
    });

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA ' + socket.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
    });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

**http server**

```
var http = require('http')
 , server = http.createServer(sourcehandler)

server.listen(8080)

function sourcehandler (req, res) {

   req.on('error', function (e) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(({err:e, msg: "Request Stream Error", code: 500})))
   })

   req.on('close', function () {
      console.log("REQUEST CLOSING")
   })

   req.on('data', function (data) {
       console.log(data)
   })

   console.log(req.headers)

}
```

**client socket (Python)**

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost', 8080))

sock.send("POST / HTTP/1.1\n")
sock.send("Host: 127.0.0.1\n")
sock.send("User-Agent: Python\n")
sock.send("some data\n")
```

When I run these independently, the HTTP server closes before firing a 'data' event.

The net server prints:

```
DATA 127.0.0.1: POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Python
some data
```

The http server prints:

```
{ host: '127.0.0.1', 'user-agent': 'Python' }
REQUEST CLOSING
```

What causes the HTTP server to fire the 'close' event?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: you have two servers listening to the same IP/PORT probably they conflict with each other if you are running at the same time.

Comment: Not an answer to this question but please use the [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) package for dealing with HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I missing several details.

My main confusion was that "streaming" data with `http` is really just sending a chunked request, which is done like so:

```
sock.send("POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n")
sock.send("Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n")
sock.send("User-Agent: Python\r\n")
sock.send("Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n")
sock.send("Connection: close")
sock.send("\r\n\r\n")

# Now send the body of the message
# Each "chunk" of data must be preceded with the length of the chunk, in hex
s = 'some data'
sock.send(format(len(s), 'x')+'\r\n') # Sending the length of the data in hex
sock.send(s+'\r\n') # Sending the data

sock.send("0\r\n")
sock.send("\r\n")

sock.close()
```

Thanks for the hints everybody!

Answer (score 0):

> When I run these independently, the HTTP server closes before firing a 'data' event.

It's probably because there is no data in your request, only headers.

You probably wanted to write something like this instead:

```
sock.send("POST / HTTP/1.1\n")
sock.send("Host: 127.0.0.1\n")
sock.send("User-Agent: Python\n")
sock.send("Content-Length: 9\n")
sock.send("\n")
sock.send("some data\n")
```